# Is it possible to cache ?wc-ajax=get_variation

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, server-load

I have been trying to figure out a way to make this work for awhile.

I have a site, pizza shop. It has a promo, two pizzas. The product is any 2 or 15 types of pizza. I have the 15 types of pizzas set up as two separate variations, first pizza and second pizza.

I have w3tc setup and working well. I have engintron running and cloudflare free tier.

I have DB and objects set up to cache, but only for 3 minutes.

My server gets murdered every time I have a half dozen people look through all the variations on this, and other similar products. I can easily have 100+ shopping/ordering if no one is looking at these promo products. But if I have a half dozen people looking at the promo, my server load goes through the roof.

Is it possible to cache these request? They change maybe once every couple of months. I think there has to be a way to deal with this but I can't figure it out.